# Custom search in Yii model for CGrid view on relational data

Tags: yii

I have a custom search in my model noted below,  It works with out any issue in MySQL and when I step through the code with NetBeans Yii builds the query properly but returns no rows.  I run the same query in MySQL and I get the intended rows of information.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
public function fnSearch(){

    $nParts=explode(" ", $_REQUEST['fnText']);

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->condition='first_name like ":fname" and last_name like ":lname"';
    $criteria->params=array(';fname'=>trim($nParts[0]).'%', ':lname'=>trim($nParts[1]).'%');

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));

}
```

My test form looks like this:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'test-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<?= CHtml::textField('fnText'); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'employees-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$model->fnSearch(),
//            'filter'=>$model,
            'columns'=>array(
                'first_name',
                'last_name',

                array(
                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                ),
            ),
)); ?>
```

The controller has this:

```
public function actionTest(){
            $model=new Employees;
            $this->render('test',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
            ));
        }
```

Comment: Typo: `$criteria->params=array(';fname'` should be ` $criteria->params=array(':fname'`

Comment: Fixed typo and still not getting any returns on rows.

Comment: Parameters automatically get wrapped in quotations.  So write your condition like this instead `first_name like :fname and last_name like :lname`